# Segfault apparently when affecting value to an int

Tags: c, debugging, pointers, memory-management, pointer-arithmetic

I'm working on a memory allocator in C (rewriting *malloc* and *free* from scratch). I use a heap created by *mmap*, and headers before each chunk of memory to get information concerning the chunk. I use the following structure to handle my free list (the "list" of all free chunks) :

```
typedef struct node_t {
         long int        size;
         struct node_t  *next;
}node_t;
```

When allocating a new memory block, I use a temporary `node_t* temp`. We have also `node_t* startfree` a pointer to the head of my free list.
The variable `int size` is a parameter of the function that contains that part of the code.
`bheader_t` is another structure that we'll use later.

```
node_t* temp = (node_t*) (startfree+size+sizeof(bheader_t));
printf("DEBUG : temp %p\n",temp );
printf("DEBUG : startfree %p, size = %ld, next = %p \n",startfree, startfree-> size, startfree -> next );`  
printf("DEBUG : future value of temp->size : %ld\n",startfree -> size - size -sizeof(bheader_t));
printf("DEBUG : We want to do temp(%p)->size = startfree(%p)->size (=%ld) - size (=%d) - sizeof(bheader_t) (=%ld)\n", temp, startfree, startfree->size, size, sizeof(bheader_t));
temp -> size = startfree->size - size -sizeof(bheader_t);
printf("DEBUG : temp %p, size : %ld\n",temp,temp->size );
temp -> next = startfree -> next;
startfree = temp;
```

In some cases it goes well, but in others this is what I get (in *gdb*) :

```
DEBUG : temp 0x7ffff7ff0a0c
DEBUG : startfree 0x7ffff7ef094c, size = 996000, next = (nil)
DEBUG : future value of temp->size : 930452 
DEBUG : We want to do temp(0x7ffff7ff0a0c)->size = startfree(0x7ffff7ef094c)->size (=996000) - size (=65536) - sizeof(bheader_t) (=12)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7bd7a69 in Mem_Alloc_NF (size=65536) at src/nextfit.c:108
108          `temp -> size = startfree->size - size -sizeof(bheader_t);`
```

Segfault on a simple `int` affectation ! Any ideas what it could be ?

Comment: Thanks ! Couldn't figure out how to do it nicely (I just forgot the 4 spaces at the beginning)

Comment: Faulty address (`0x00007ffff7bd7a69`) does not correspond to `temp`'s (`0x7ffff7ff0a0c`) nor `startfree` (`0x7ffff7ef094c`).

Comment: The faulty address is not even in my heap ! I think it's the address in the generated byte-code

Answer (score 0):

`node_t* temp = (node_t*) (startfree+size+sizeof(bheader_t));` is almost certainly wrong. If `startfree` is of type `node_t *`, then this will add `(size + sizeof(bheader_t)) * sizeof(node_t)` to the raw pointer. I suspect you really want `node_t* temp = (node_t*) ((char *)startfree+size+sizeof(bheader_t));`.

Comment: I still get the segfault with this correction... but it could be a part of the problem.